# When sending notifications, it gives an error

Tags: laravel, push

When sending notifications to a large number of users through the queue, after sending half of them all falls into an error

> (GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException: cURL error 6: Could not resolve host: fcm.googleapis.com (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) for https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send in /var/www/jai/vendor/guzzlehttp/guzzle/src/Handler/CurlFactory.php:210).

After that, it stops and does not continue working. Tell me how to handle this error and continue further execution of the queue.

```
public function handle(): void
{
    try {
        $usersGroup = User::query()->whereNotNull('fcm_token')
            ->select(['id', 'fcm_token', 'gender']);

        if ($this->group === UserNotification::GROUP_MALE) {
            $usersGroup = $usersGroup->where('gender', '=', User::MALE);
        }


        if ($this->group === UserNotification::GROUP_FEMALE) {
            $usersGroup = $usersGroup->where('gender', User::FEMALE);
        }

        $usersGroup->chunk(1500, function ($users) {

            foreach ($users as $user) {
                Log::channel('notification')
                    ->debug("Sending push notification to {$this->group} user group:", [
                        'user_id' => $user->id,
                        'fcm_token' => $user->fcm_token
                    ]);
                $this->fcmService->send($user->fcm_token, $this->title, $this->body);
            }
        });
    }catch (ConnectException $e){
        Log::error('Ошибка ConnectException: ' . $e->getMessage());
    }

}
```

Comment: Please add code snippet of what isn't working

Comment: `Could not resolve host: fcm.googleapis.com` means it can no longer find that host. If it happens in the middle of a large queue, then it could be something in your own/server network dropping the connection or throttling it

Comment: Can you tell me how I can ignore this error and continue executing the queue?

Comment: You really can't *ignore* it, since it means it won't send. If it's a loop, use a try/catch, and pause (sleep) occasionally. If it's not a loop, you may want to chunk the users and loop it.

Comment: I've added a snippet of code.

Comment: I need to make sure that when this exception is thrown I don't interrupt the task.

Comment: Put a try/catch around just the Log::channel/send. I'd also suggest a sleep after the foreach, just a few seconds, to let the network have some breathing space.

Comment: I have performed these actions, but the error on the server did not go away, if you put sleep, it takes a very long time to send and falls into timeout, what can you advise for faster operation? Is it possible that the problem is on the server because locally I have everything working?